# El value de mi DropMenuButton no se actualiza

Tags: flutter

Tengo un el siguiente statefulwidget, la funcion que uso para crear el drop es rowSelecBox  que le mando unos ciertos parametros.... la cuestion es que no se actualiza el value cuando apreto en las opciones del drop ... es decir no se actualiza a pesar de que hago un setstate y todo eso noce donde estara el error mmmm

```
 String estadoController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: (){
        showDialog(
          barrierDismissible: false,
          context: context,
          child: AlertDialog(
            title: Text('¿Descartar registro?'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Si'),
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  moveToLastScreen();
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('No'),
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          )
        );
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon( Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: (){
              showDialog(
                barrierDismissible: false,
                context: context,
                child: AlertDialog(
                  title: Text('¿Descartar registro?'),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('Si'),
                    onPressed: (){
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      moveToLastScreen();
                    },
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('No'),
                    onPressed: (){
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  ),
                  ],
                )
              );
            },
          ),
          elevation: 0.0,
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text('Añadir Mascota', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(width: 0.5)
                ),
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 200.0,
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Center ( child: _image == null ? Text('Añade una foto',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)) : Image.file(_image)),
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: 5.0,
                      right: 5.0,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 60.0,
                        width: 60.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
                          color: Colors.white,
                          boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                            blurRadius: 0.1,
                          )]
                        ),
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon( Icons.edit),
                          onPressed: ()async{
                            var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
                            setState((){
                              _image = image; 
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Card(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      rowTitle('Datos generales'),
                      rowTextField(context,'Nombre ','ej: condorito',20,1,nombreController),
                      rowTextField(context,'Ubicación ','Refugio o domicilio ',20,1,ubicacionController),
                      rowTextField(context,'Contacto ','telefono/correo/etc ',40,2,contactoController),
                      rowSelecBox(context, opcionesEstado, 'Estado',estadoController),
                      SizedBox(height: 15.0,)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Card(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(height: 15.0,),
                      rowTitle('Datos del animal'),
                      rowSelecBox(context, opcionesEspecies, 'Especie',especieController),
                      rowTextField(context,'Edad ','meses/años/desconocido',20,1,edadController),
                      Divider(),
                      rowChecTile('Desparacitado ',datosMedicosController[0]),
                      rowChecTile('Esterilizado ',datosMedicosController[1]),
                      rowChecTile('MicroChip ',datosMedicosController[2]),
                      rowChecTile('Vacunado ',datosMedicosController[3]),
                      Divider(),
                      rowSelecBox(context, opcionesActividad, 'Actividad',actividadController),
                      rowSelecBox(context, opcionesTamanio, 'Tamaño',tamanioController),
                      rowSelecBox(context, opcionesSexo, 'Sexo',sexoController),
                      SizedBox(height: 15.0,),
                    ], 
                  ),
                )
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Card(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                        rowTextField(context,'Mas sobre mi ','historia/etc ',50,4,masCosasController),
                        rowTextField(context,'Requisitos ','adopcion responsable',20,2,requisitosController),
                        SizedBox(height: 15.0,),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: (){},
                child: Container(
                  height: 60.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all( Radius.circular(15)),
                    boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                      blurRadius: 0.1
                    )]
                  ),
                  child: Center(child: Text('Agregar', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 15.0,),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ),
    ); 
  }
```

y  esta es la funcion

```
  Widget rowSelecBox(BuildContext context, List lista, String title, String controller){

    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(title, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
        DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
            child: DropdownButton( 
              value: controller,
              items: getOcionesDropdown(lista),
              onChanged: (String opt){
                setState(() {
                  controller = opt;;
                  print(controller);
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> getOcionesDropdown(List lista){

    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> aux = new List();

    lista.forEach((especie){
      aux.add( DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Text(especie),
        value: especie,
      ));
    });
    return aux;
  }
```

como dije en el titulo, cuando aprieto las opciones no cambia el value del drop.. a pesar de que el print(controller) que hago si me muestra el valor que seleccione...

Comment: quien dice funcion dice widget .... xd

Comment: Trata de replicar el error en un ejemplo más sencillo para que podamos probarlo y ayudarte

Comment: El problema es que estas llamando `setState()` desde un widget retornado a través de un método.